# Using output of one function within another (PHP)

Tags: php

I have two functions within a PHP class. I want to use the output of the first function within the second, but I always get an internal server error.

Simplified example:

```
<?php 
class TestClass{

    private function return_string(){
        $test = 'test variable';

        return $test;
    }

    private function encode_string() {
        $x = return_string();

        return json_encode($x);
    }
}

?>
```

I've tried returning the string directly from return_string() (not that this is what I want) and even this still gives an error. If I set $x to a string instead of the function return_string() it works fine, so everything in the encode_string() function seems fine. Not sure what else to check.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$x = $this->return_string();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since both methods are of same class you can call it by `$this` keyword.
`$this->return_string();` will do the job.